# Difficulty echoing from a live MQTT feed

Tags: bash, shell, echo

I am unable to see what I receive through the MQTT/mosquitto stream by means of `echo`ing.

My code is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

`mosquitto_sub -d -t +/# >>mqtt_log.csv`

mqtt_stream_variable=`sed '$!d' mqtt_log.csv`

echo "$mqtt_stream_variable"
```

First line subscribes to the mqtt stream and appends the output to the `mqtt_log.csv` file. Then I `sed '$!d' mqtt_log.csv` so I get the last lines value assigned to the `mqtt_stream` variable, I later echo this.

When I execute this - I don't see any `echo`ing I was curious to know how I could do this? When I `cat mqtt_log.csv` there are things in there. So the `mosquitto_sub -d -t +/# >>mqtt_log.csv` part is working. It's just the `echo`ing that is being problematic.

---

Ideally after ``` mqtt_stream=``sed '$!d' mqtt_log.csv ```  I would like to play around with the values in `mqtt_log.csv` [as it's a csv string]. So by means of `echo`ing I can see what the `mqtt_stream_variable` variable holds

Comment: You're making your life very difficult by trying to use mosquitto_sub I'd say. Why not write a simple Python client to do exactly what you want? (Or C, Java, ...)

Comment: @ralight I'm fairly new to programming, this the lack of experience. Any pointers in how to do write python client?

Comment: Sure, try take a look at http://git.eclipse.org/c/paho/org.eclipse.paho.mqtt.python.git/tree/examples/sub.py then add the modification and republishing of your data to the on_message() callback.

Comment: More generally, these links: http://eclipse.org/paho/clients/python/ http://eclipse.org/paho/clients/python/docs/

Comment: @ralight On the way home, I was thinking if I "subscribe" ie `tail` the file `mqtt_log.csv`. So first program will record the stream to `mqtt_log.csv` the second program will `tail` the `mqtt_log.csv` file. But one problem is how will the second program know there is new datum in `mqtt_log.csv`? Will I use an while loop, to constanly tail `mqtt_log.csv` with the second program?

Comment: I think you want a single program and (unless you want it for other purposes) no mqtt_log.csv.

Comment: @ralight I would like a single program, but if there is an easier way of doing it, i thought breaking it down to two programs - but nevertheless I will look into python. Is it ok if I ask for help along the way should I become stuck?

Comment: Yes, but on the Eclipse Paho mailing list would be most appropriate rather than here.

Answer (score 0):

The mosquitto_sub command will never return and sed will read the empty file before any messages are written to it and then exit.

How about something like this

```
#!/bin/bash
mosquitto_sub -d -t +/# | tee -a mqtt_log.csv | sed '$!d'
```

No need for all the sub shells and pipes will get you what you want.

The only other thing is why the need for both wild cards in the topic? +/# should be the same as just # (you will probably need to wrap the # in quotes on it's own)

Comment: One confusion I have is _how can I assign a variable (`mqtt_stream_variable`) to the output_ The reason I ask is that the output will be used with mysql to update various things on a website immediately after its received from the mqtt feed. This is why I need to 'manipulate' what the `mqtt_stream_vairable` holds. Any further suggestions will be highly appreciated! Many thanks!

Comment: In that case I really wouldn't do this in a shell script, this should be in something a bit more capable (e.g. javascript or python). Because you are going to need a loop to chop up the output for each message received